# How to combine glossary with grammar?

Tags: latex

When using acronyms from glossary by:

```
\newacronym{lk}{LK}{Lebkuchen}
```

The intext will show:

```
Ich werde Lebkuchen (LK) essen.
```

But if I want to combine it with other word I will get the intext:

```
Ich werde Lebkuchen (LK)haus bauen
```

Can I fix this without having to change my sentence?

i.e.

```
Ich werde Lebkuchenhaus (LK) bauen
```

Minimal code base:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackag{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{lk}{LK}{Lebkuchen}
\begin{document}
    \printacronyms
    \newpage
    Ich werde \gls{lk}haus bauen. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]

Comment: Added minimal code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use such a composite word when you first define an acronym, people might assume the acronym would stand for the hole composite word. However if you really must use it like this, you could use something like the following workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{lk}{LK}{Lebkuchen}
\begin{document}
    \printacronyms
    \newpage
    
    Das \gls{lk}
    
    Ich werde ein \Acrlong{lk}[haus] (\acrshort{lk}) bauen. 
    
    Das \gls{lk}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]